# How to check and rewrite all URLs inside a Typescript String - Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular12, angular13, ionic6

I am using Ionic 6 on Angular 13 and I have a json string that has the full text with html codes in it. I need to check the `anchor` tags and `img` urls in that string and rewrite the url domain name if required.

For example, I want this `fulltext:string` variable:

```
fulltext:string = 
"<p>This is the intro text</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="downloads/category/886-download-pdf">PDF 1 <img src="images/886-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>

<li><a href="downloads/category/887-download-pdf">PDF 2 <img src="images/887-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>

<li><a href="https://website.com/downloads/category/888-download-pdf">PDF 3 <img src="https://website.com/images/888-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>"
```

To become:

```
"<p>This is the intro text</p>
<ul>
<li><a href="https://website.com/downloads/category/886-download-pdf">PDF 1 <img src="https://website.com/images/886-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>

<li><a href="https://website.com/downloads/category/887-download-pdf">PDF 2 <img src="https://website.com/images/887-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>

<li><a href="https://website.com/downloads/category/888-download-pdf">PDF 3 <img src="https://website.com/images/888-download-pdf.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>"
```

From what I understand so far, I think I need to do the following:

1. Scan the variable string for all `anchor` tags and `img` tags.
2. See if these urls already has the domain name in it.
3. If it doesn't, prefix the domain names to these urls.

I tried creating a function in Typescript (or probably better creating a pipe for this), but I am unable to get this done. One of the first hurdle I have is, when I try to get the tags using `querySelectorAll` or `getElementById`, it does not work on string. I also tried declaring it as `HTMLElement` as per some suggestions here and I am unable to proceed through.

Can you kindly help me out here on how this can done in Angular Typescript please?

Comment: Is it expected that all hrefs and srcs end with the value you want to keep? That is, that you want to keep whole value after the last / in any of those tags?

Comment: Thank you @MishaMashina for reading my post. Yeah, you are right. the value of the urls stays the same. i just need to add the website source so it goes to that domain to fetch that data since its from an ionic app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/plain-angular6-htjxrv

I made arrays of end values of the old hrefs and srcs by splitting the original text, then build the arrays of new href and src values by adding your intended paths to the content of old hrefs and srcs arrays. Finally, replaced the old href and src values in the text with elements from the array of new values.

I'm sure it can be done differently, but I think this is clear enough when you look at the code.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much @MishaMashina Thats exactly what I was struggling with. I really appreciate you for taking the time to help me with this. Thank you, really, so much.